# Upload images using Svelte Kit Api

Tags: javascript, typescript, post, svelte, form-data

I'm making a file uploading API on Svelte. You send images via form-data and the API saves it locally.

This is what my API looks like:

```
export const post: RequestHandler = async ({ request })  => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    console.log(data)
    return { status: 200, body: "h"};
};
```

The request's body:

```
----------------------------930945094336727102920559
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="index.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����       

basically this, I can not paste the rest
```

I just get `FormData {}` on the console

How can I save this image locally using node:fs or something similar

Answer (score 1):

`FormData` has to be read and will not automatically be serialized. From the body it looks like the input already has a suitable name and is posted correctly, so you should be able to just read that as a `File`.

e.g.

```
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

export const post: RequestHandler = async ({ request })  => {
    const data = await request.formData();
    const file = data.get('image') as File;
    await fs.writeFile(`D:/${file.name}`, file.stream());

    return { status: 200, body: "h"};
};
```